# Command glossary for dataflow?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm experimenting with the Dataflow Python SDK and would like some sort of reference as to what the various commands do, their required args and their recommended syntax.

So after
`import google.cloud.dataflow as df`

Where can I read up on df.Create, df.Write, df.FlatMap, df.CombinePerKey, etc.  ?  Has anybody put together such a reference?

Is there anyplace (link please) where all the possible Apache Beam / Dataflow commands are collected and explained?

Comment: I found this for Java, but wonder if there's a similar resource for Python?    https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/

Answer (score 1):

There is not yet a pydoc server running for Dataflow Python.  However, you can easily run your own in order to browse: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowPythonSDK#a-quick-tour-of-the-source-code

Comment: Not able to get that to work.   Using directions from link. I get "ValueError: could not find object"  and then I get nothing returned when I try "find / -name google.cloud.dataflow.html" on commanmd line

Comment: It looks like pydocs is calling up the docs from python3.4.3 which is also installed on my machine. I've set and exported and sourced `PYTHONDOCS='/usr/share/doc/python2.7/html/'` but it errors with     `bash: /usr/share/doc/python2.7/html/: No such file or directory`  Any advice?

Comment: I've found a workaround.  After starting python w `python2.7`     (I have both 2.7.6 and 3.4.3 on my machine)  if I `import pydoc` and then `import google.cloud.dataflow as df`  I can now (in the console) call up the documentation by `pydoc.help(df.pipeline)`  or `pydoc.help(df.Create)` and so on for whatever module I need help on.  But I sure would like to get this into a browser.